# SSRS Date Parameter Interpretation Issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I'm looking for some help with SSRS 2016, and Date Parameters.

We have multiple reports that have date pickers, and we need to keep the date pickers. The issue is, when we load the report through the web portal the dates comes out as MM/DD/YYYY and remain that way. We have an application which is used by our employees, and it hosts the Report Viewer Control. In this control, when the reports are loaded the dates show as DD/MM/YYYY, then after you hit the View Report button, it changes to MM/DD/YYYY causing the date to be interpreted incorrectly (05/03/2018 becomes March 5 instead of May 3, etc).

We have been attempting to change all of our Dates and Region settings throughout the company to YYYY-MM-DD, so all of our computers and servers are set to that region. Also, all of our reports have a Language of en-CA, but they are still being formatted and interpreted incorrectly.

I have attempted to set the Parameters default value to:

```
=CDATE(format(Today(), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

, but even that didn't change how the date parameter was formatted.

I was hoping for a place in SSRS 2016 where you could either set the Display format of the Parameter fields, or a global setting which has a global date format, but I don't believe that exists.

Is it possible to force a specific date format to Date Parameters in SSRS 2016? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `dateformat` on the database server.

```
USE [ReportServer]
GO

DBCC USEROPTIONS
```

[image: query results]

```
SET dateformat ymd
SELECT [dateformat] FROM sys.[syslanguages] s WHERE s.[name] = @@language
```